# declare form variables and arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to declare variables and arrays from a form (post) but it seems the arrays are not being processed:

```
// is this a better practise than directly pass the entire $_POST?
$list = array('use', 'type', 'status', 'bhk', 'baths', 'size', 'location', 'price', 'description');
foreach($list as $name) {
    if ($name != 'description')
        $var = "\$" . $name . "=filter_input(INPUT_POST, '" . $name . "', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);";
    else if ($name == 'description')
        $var = "\$" . $name . "=filter_input(INPUT_POST, '" . $name . "', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);";
}

$area_1 = $size['area1'] != '' ? $size['area1'] : 0;
$area_2 = $size['area2'] != '' ? $size['area2'] : 0;
$city   = $location['city'];
$zone   = $location['zone'];
$sale   = $price['sale'] != '' ? $price['sale'] : 0;
$rent   = $price['rent'] != '' ? $price['rent'] : 0;
```

Could be that some of those inputs are long numbers? Like `$price['sale']` (up to 999999) or `$size['area1']` (up to 999). Since they don't need any unit type I prefer storing them as integers rather than strings. But tell me if the length is a problem.

EDIT: (FIX by @**swidmann** in comments)

```
$$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $name, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

Solution: (by @**swidmann** in comments)

```
$$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $name, FILTER_DEFAULT , FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY)
```

Comment: why are you using eval?

Comment: Using `eval` is nearly always a bad idea. Using `eval` on user input, in an attempt to increase security, is a bloody terrible idea!

Comment: I'm using `eval` to make the variables, I thought it didn't affect the user input. What is the alternative?

Comment: `POST description= "a', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); unlink(__FILE__);"` Bad things happen

Comment: What are you actually tring to do? Im sure there is a simple, secure way to do it, if only i could work out your intentions

Comment: Just declare the variables from a form to store them in a db.

Comment: you can make variables like this `$$name = filter_input( INPUT_POST , $name, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );` with `$$name` you can define a variable with the name of  the string content `$name`

Comment: This sounds and reads like a bad idea from front to back -- *Why* are you generating variables based on user-input? -- you already have the names and data in the `$_POST` or `$_GET` arrays -- there is no need to do what you do -- I strongly suspect an XY-Problem

Comment: Sorry, the variable names are not based on user-input. They are based on the names from my array.

Comment: There's still a problem, the arrays are always 0. And I made sure to fill the inputs. What is the problem?

Comment: i think you need an additional filter, **if the input is an array**: FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY => http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

Comment: Right, there's another filter for arrays... Thanks @swidmann!

Comment: @ChazyChaz: you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create variables from your array you should use `$$` instead of concatenating a string an run `eval()`, because [eval() is evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php).

You can make variables like this:

`$$name = filter_input( INPUT_POST , $name, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );` with `$$name` you can define a variable with the name of the string content `$nam`e

If your input can be an array, please take a look at [filter_input_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input-array.php) or [filter_input()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) with the option `FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY`, depends on what you need.

**Here is an approach:**

```
// is this a better practise than directly pass the entire $_POST?
$list = array( 'use', 'type', 'status', 'bhk', 'baths', 'size', 'location', 'price', 'description' );
foreach ( $list as $name ) {
    if ( $name != 'description' ) {
        if( is_array( $_POST[$name] ) ) {
            // I think you should also check for other types if needed (i.e. string)
            $$name = filter_input( INPUT_POST , $name, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT , FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY );
        } else {
            $$name = filter_input( INPUT_POST , $name, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT  );
        }
    } else if ( $name == 'description' ) {
        $$name = filter_input( INPUT_POST , $name, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    }
}

$area_1 = $size['area1'] != '' ? $size['area1'] : 0;
$area_2 = $size['area2'] != '' ? $size['area2'] : 0;
$city = $location['city'];
$zone = $location['zone'];
$sale = $price['sale'] != '' ? $price['sale'] : 0;
$rent = $price['rent'] != '' ? $price['rent'] : 0;
```

**if you are not sure about the input, you can try the option FILTER_DEFAULT:**

```
$$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $name, FILTER_DEFAULT , FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY)
```